# How to push objects into array in my case

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push the objects to an array and the differences of the objects are just one property.

Code snippet:

```
var categoryList = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'...more]
var productlist = [];
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var nextYear = year++

for (var a = 0; a < categoryList.length; a++) {
    productList.push({
        date: year + '-' + categoryList[a],
        'items': [{
            'quatity': 0 'type': 'new'
        }]
    });

    productList.push({
        date: nextYear + '-' + categoryList[a],
        'items': [{
            'quantity': 0 'type': 'new',
        }]
    });
}
```

I need to add this year and next year to the object but I am not sure if there are any better ways to simplified the above codes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are missing semicolons and your code contains illegal characters.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. There are some small syntax errors in the code you posted, do you want to fix them or are you asking if the code can be simplified?

Comment: I can't understand your needs.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion, so lack of semicolons is not a problem here. Besides that, what illegal characters are you referring to? I don’t see any.

Comment: @icktoofay: This "`...more]`" is illegal. Do not sacrifice proper syntax for laziness. I hope you don't run your JavaScript through JSHint. God forbid you use JSLint. Douglas Crockford would have a hayday...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: That’s invalid syntax, but not invalid characters, and the intent was clearly visible. I’m not sure the JSHint/JSLint remark is relevant; on Stack Overflow, we deal with JavaScript as a whole, not restricting ourselves to an arbitrary subset unless specified otherwise in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code you will (currently) end up with `year == 2015` and `nextYear == 2014`. I think that you meant to do this:

```
var nextYear = year + 1;
```

You can refactor the code to use a function to add items to the product list. (I assume that the `quatity` property is just a typo, so that the only difference is the year.)

```
function addProduct(year, product) {
  productList.push({
    date: year + '-' + product,
    items: [{
      quantity: 0,
      type: 'new'
    }]
  });
}

for (var a = 0; a < categoryList.length; a++) {
  addProduct(year, categoryList[a]);
  addProduct(nextYear, categoryList[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this;

```
function addProduct(prodDate) {
    productList.push({
        'date':prodDate,
        'items' : [ {
            'quatity' : 0,
            'type' : 'new'
        } ]
    });
}
for (var a=0; a < categoryList.length; a++) {
    addProduct(year + '-' + categoryList[a]);
    addProduct(nextYear + '-' + categoryList[a]);
}
```